# Count number of times a date is in DB

Tags: sql, google-visualization

Im looking for some help creating a graph using the google chart API

I have some idea of how i want to code it, but i need help turning psuedo into real code.

I have a database with site users. Each user has a date that they joined. I want to count how many people join on each date, then put this into a string for the google chart API url.

im thinking something like this, but need some help:

```
Set up DB connection etc...

select date from site_users, count and group by date_joined under column called 'number', as to give a 2 column table result -> Date and Number of joins.

while (sql query){
    $date .= $row['date_joined']."|";
    $number .= $row['number']."|";
}

construct google chart url
$url = "www.google.cometc...".$date."&".$number;

<img src=".&url." alt="chart" />
```

Some help would be great, i think the part im struggling with is the sql statement.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date, count(*) as users FROM site_users GROUP BY date;
```

or if you need WHERE:

```
SELECT date, count(*) as users FROM site_users
    WHERE date > '2008-01-01'
    GROUP BY date;
```

The GROUP BY is the important part. It generates an aggregate report. What you're count()ing is the number of rows in each GROUP (in this case, date).

Comment: Thankyou, i plan to only get dates within the last 30 days, so would i just plug the WHERE date <= etc... on the end of that statement?

Comment: No, add WHERE before GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Here is correct SQL, but you'll have to fix the specific field names:

```
select date,count(*) as number
from site_users
group by date;
```

If the date field is a timestamp or other type which contains times as well, a truncation is needed (in MySQL):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%e-%d') as date,count(*) as number
from site_users
group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%e-%d');
```

Comment: Thankyou, so if i understand that correct, its going to create a new column called count, and store the number in that column?

Comment: It will generate an output column called count; it does not modify the table.

Comment: Brilliant thankyou, i wont be using any time, but thanks anyway !